# Can R be wrong on logical conditions?

Tags: r, logic

I was crosschecking my code and essentially it appears the R doesn't give the right output on logical conditions. How possible? I have a dataframe such this one:

```
  head(hope)  
                times        users signal log diff  
1 2014-01-13 00:00:16 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31  
2 2014-01-13 00:00:47 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31  
3 2014-01-13 00:01:18 00250902DC7D   true  ON   30  
4 2014-01-13 00:01:48 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31  
5 2014-01-13 00:02:19 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31  
6 2014-01-13 00:02:50 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31
```

In column there are 14 different users. If I try to select only the data for the user '00250902FA92', I write as follows:

```
> mmm<-hope[users=="00250902FA92",]
```

If I crosscheck with 'head' and' tail' I dont get the data for the wished user:

```
> head(mmm)  
                    times        users signal log diff  
44319 2014-01-17 12:29:28 00250902FA92   true  ON   17  
44324 2014-01-17 12:30:06 00250902FA92   true  ON    5  
44329 2014-01-17 12:30:42 00250902FA92   true  ON    3  
44334 2014-01-17 12:31:16 00250902FA92   true  ON   15  
44339 2014-01-17 12:32:01 00250902FA92   true  ON   10  
44344 2014-01-17 12:32:42 00250902FA92   true  ON    5
```

****OK****

but with (tail):

```
> tail(mmm)  
       times    users signal log diff  
152158 2014-01-16 23:50:22 002509030E53   true  ON   14  
152161 2014-01-16 23:50:46 002509030E53   true  ON    7  
152164 2014-01-17 11:22:11 002509030E53   true  ON   13  
152167 2014-01-17 11:22:26 002509030E53   true  ON    7  
152170 2014-01-17 11:22:55 002509030E53   true  ON    1  
152173 2014-01-17 11:23:03 002509030E53   true  ON    9
```

****ERROR**** _***Why 00250903053?***_

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
mmm<-hope[hope$users=="00250902FA92",]
```

Or

```
mmm<-subset( hope, users=="00250902FA92")
```

Comment: Many thanks :), you know it's the saturday night/sunday morning and I was close to trouw the pc from the window :)

Comment: @antonio And that's why you don't `attach` a data frame.